# Python: Running multi variables using the same function at the same time. New to Python

Tags: python, function, finance, yahoo-finance, google-finance

I've been working with python for the past few days, and started working on a project. Currently trying to figure out how to execute the same function using multiple variables (In this case, Stock symbols). Preferably with one input() separated with a comma or something. I've hit a snag with this last part though. Can anyone point me in the direction of where to go next? (Running the same function with multiple variables at the same time.)

Here is my code:

```
#Google + Yahoo Finance Stock Lookup
from googlefinance import getQuotes
from yahoo_finance import Share
import googlefinance
import datetime, time
import os
from datetime import datetime


tDate = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (tDate)
tDateConv = str(tDate)

try:
    os.chdir('/Users/Jakes_Macbook/Desktop/Python/Stocks')
except Exception:
    print('Default Path does not exsist, make sure your directory is   right.')
    pass

run = True
while run == True:
    print('You are currently storing the file in ')
    print(os.getcwd())
    print('type "yes" to continue')
confirm = input()
if confirm == 'yes':
    print ('ok\n')
    try:
        os.makedirs(tDateConv)
    except Exception:
        pass
    os.chdir(tDateConv)
    print('File will be saved to:')
    print(os.getcwd())
    break
else:
    print('Where do you want to store the file?')
    changeDir = input()
    os.chdir(changeDir)


print('What Stock or Stocks would you like to look up?')
stockSymbol = input()

def runStocks():

    print (" ")
    print ("Stock Symbol: " + stockSymbol)
    stockSymbolYhoo = Share(stockSymbol)

    stockFile = open(str(stockSymbol)+'.txt', 'a')

    dicStored = googlefinance.getQuotes(stockSymbol)[0]
    numStoredPrice = float(dicStored['LastTradePrice'])
    print('Stock Open: ' + stockSymbolYhoo.get_open())
    print ("Stored Price: " + str(numStoredPrice))
    stockFile.write(str("\n" + "Stock Symbol: " + stockSymbol + "\n"))
    stockFile.write(str("\n" + "Open Price: " + stockSymbolYhoo.get_open() + "\n"))
    stockFile.write(str("Stored Price: " + str(numStoredPrice)+'\n'))


    runs = 0
while runs < 5:
    stor = googlefinance.getQuotes(stockSymbol)[0]
    price = stor['LastTradePrice']
    print(str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + " | " + price)
    stockFile.write(str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + " | Price " + price + ' \n')

    numPrice = float(price)

    if numPrice < numStoredPrice*float(.995):
        print ("buy")

    time.sleep(5)
    runs = runs + 1

stockFile.close()

runStocks()
```

My goal is to have each stock symbol, that is inputted, create its own file in the folder for today. I'm pretty sure i can figure out how to do that once i get multiple functions going. Thanks in advance.

Also, let me know if you have any important suggestions or best practices. This is like my second day working with python. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass them into the function:

```
# Note the definition was updated to be able to pass in a stockSymbol
def runStocks(stockSymbol):

    print (" ")
    print ("Stock Symbol: " + stockSymbol)
    stockSymbolYhoo = Share(stockSymbol)

    stockFile = open(str(stockSymbol)+'.txt', 'a')

    dicStored = googlefinance.getQuotes(stockSymbol)[0]
    numStoredPrice = float(dicStored['LastTradePrice'])
    print('Stock Open: ' + stockSymbolYhoo.get_open())
    print ("Stored Price: " + str(numStoredPrice))
    stockFile.write(str("\n" + "Stock Symbol: " + stockSymbol + "\n"))
    stockFile.write(str("\n" + "Open Price: " + stockSymbolYhoo.get_open() + "\n"))
    stockFile.write(str("Stored Price: " + str(numStoredPrice)+'\n'))

stockSymbols = input("Enter stock symbols separated by commas").split(",")

for stockSymbol in stockSymbols:
    runStocks(stockSymbol) # Call your function in a loop
```